# Calculating APY for every user in a shared environment

Tags: algorithms

It is actually a real-world programming problem that I'm looking for a mathematical answer to solve it:
There is a lending pool that pays interest to user-supplied cryptocurrencies, this interest rate we know as APY is calculated dynamically based on the capital efficiency of each pool (e.g. number of users that borrow from that pool and amount that is being borrowed. So, it does not apply the normal APY formula).
If we provide `X` units of -for example- `ShitCoin` or `SHC` to DiarrheaPool, we get an equivalent amount of `SHC-LP` which can be later used for redeeming the original asset (there is a `1:1` co-relation between them). Interest is allocated to each participant in the pool by adding directly to their `SHC-LP` tokens over time. For example, if a user provides 100 `SHC` and gets 100 `SHC-LP`, after some time that he earns 1 extra `SHC-LP` as interest, it accumulates with the current balance and his `SHC-LP` holding would be 101 (which is equivalent to 101 `SHC`). We are not aware of that interest amount in advance, but we can get `SHC-LP` balance of the user at any given time.
Now let's dive into the interesting part! A passionate user takes the responsibility of investing on behalf of his crypto-illiterate friends to share this unique smelly opportunity with them! Unfortunately, he can't create a single wallet for each and every of his genius friends, so he wants to manage all assets in his own wallet. His friends may send him any amount of `SHC` to invest at any time and may need to withdraw their `SHC` -in addition to their interest- at any time as well. He needs to somehow keeps track of interest allocated to each person, which depends on the time and amount of initial supply, but is not easily separable. Can anybody give him a hint?!

Comment: "APY is calculated dynamically based on the capital efficiency of each pool" since there is a single pool, shall we say there is a single $r(t)$? Do we know r(t)? If so, is the interest amount compounding continuously or at discrete intervals (say daily)? If not, can r(t) be computed by some proxy, say daily balance?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan We do not know r(t). Interest compounding is calculated discretely when someone borrows from the pool (upon his repay). Since we are coding in a smart contract, our ability to do any further analysis, schedule any recurrent task, or delegate part of calculations is restricted.